# Who created the "identificar-este-pelicula" tag? Can it be deleted?

Tags: support, tags

I just noticed an ID question pop up on my homepage, which shouldn't happen since I filter these out. I then noticed that it had the tag [identificar-este-pelicula](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identificar-este-pelicula).

Considering this is an English-only SE, I don't think this tag should exist. Can anyone please delete it?

Comment: Looks like it's been removed from the question. So it will be deleted in due course by script.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure who the user is who made that edit but I've rolled it back.

The edit was harmful to the question - it removed the [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) tag and added a bunch of fake, one-off tags that should not exist.

This tag (and the rest of the tags) will delete itself when the cleanup runs tonight.